# Draw ring with black shadow

Tags: android, geometry, shadow

I'm trying to draw a ring with black shadow border. I'm able to achieve this with custom view when I use any color like RED, but what I want is a transparent circle with black shadow border.

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 6.0f, 6.0f, Color.BLACK);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(70, 70, 50, mPaint); }
```

Comment: Colours use ARGB values with A being opacity. Instead of using `setColor(Colour.RED)` for `mPaint`, have you tried `setColor(0x00000000)`?

Comment: Wouldn't something completely transparent have no shadow by definition?

Comment: @Squonk It fills circle with Black color I want it to be transparent.

Comment: @Geobits An example of what I'm looking to implement in html/css is http://jsfiddle.net/JHjQ4/

Comment: did you manage to solve this ? thanks/

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is that it's drawing a *filled in* transparent circle, and setting the shadow layer to that. Since the circle is transparent, you see the whole shadow of the object through it, not just the edges you're looking for. The shadow is black, so it looks like the whole circle is black.

Try setting the Paint style to Stroke. That should leave the middle transparent, and just draw the shadow of the outer ring. It may draw the shadow in both directions, though(inner and outer), so you may have to adjust the shadow radius accordingly.

```
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: I still don't get the same result as jsfiddle.net/JHjQ4

Comment: Is there a way to draw the shadow only on the outside of it without having to adjust the radius?

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Android SDK 11 or higher? Since HoneyComb shadow rendring with hardware support had been disabled, you habe to turn on software rendering for this layer. You have to annotate your function for setting up the paint like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setUpPaint(){
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 6.0f, 6.0f, 0x80000000);

    /* --- for android:minSdkVersion="11" --- */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mPaint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to effectively draw the shadow using a fully transparent colour, as you've found so far, then remove that coloured center using PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR - leaving just the shadow on the outside.

```
PorterDuffXfermode mXferMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

// draw the src/dst example into our offscreen bitmap
int sc = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, 70 + 50, 70 + 50, null,
                                      Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG |
                                      Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG |
                                      Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                                      Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                                      Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

canvas.drawCircle(70, 70, 50, shadowPaint);
shadowPaint.setXfermode(mXferMode);
canvas.drawCircle(70, 70, 50, shadowPaint);
shadowPaint.setXfermode(null);
canvas.restoreToCount(sc);
```